# How to update variable in if else statement with reference error

Tags: python, pycharm

Working on a textbase game where you can move your character through rooms however, I keep running into an error about my position variable not being referenced

```
current_position = rooms[0]
def player_moves_south():
    if current_position == rooms[0]:
        current_position = rooms[1]
        print('welcome too the Bedroom you can now move North or East')
        player_choice = input()
        return player_choice

        return current_position
    else:
        print('error')
```

I keep getting an error saying

> 'current_position' not referenced

Can anyone help? It will be much appreciated

Comment: You have two return statements in the if statement. Your function returns player_choice, not current_position.

Comment: instead of returning two variables you should return a list or tuple like `return (player_choice, current_position)` or `return [player_choice, current_position]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried it like this.

```
def player_moves_south():
     current_position = rooms[0]
     if current_position == rooms[0]:
        print('welcome too the Bedroom you can now move North or East')
        player_choice = input()

        return player_choice

        return current_position

     else:
         print('error')

player_moves_south()
```

It worked. I put the current_position in the function and it is giving me no error.

If you want to use the current_position variable outside the function you can global it in the function. Like this

```
global current_position
current_position = rooms[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a canvas for the character to move on?

Comment: No this game is only text base and works with user inputs and text prompts

Comment: In your code, it returns player_choice first which stops the code running before it runs current_position.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).